# Days difference in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a question about SQL Server.

Table: `holidaylist`

```
Date       |  weekendStatus   | Holidaystatus
2015-12-01 |   0              | 0
2015-12-02 |   0              | 0
2015-12-03 |   0              | 0
2015-12-04 |   1              | 0
2015-12-05 |   1              | 0
2015-12-06 |   0              | 1
2015-12-07 |   0              | 0
2015-12-08 |   0              | 0
2015-12-09 |   0              | 1
2015-12-10 |   0              | 0
2015-12-11 |   0              | 0
2015-12-12 |   1              | 1
2015-12-13 |   1              | 0
```

Table: `emp`

```
empid  |  doj       | dos
1      | 2015-12-01 | 2015-12-06
2      |2015-12-01  | 2015-12-13
3      |2015-12-03  |2015-12-13
```

I want get days difference from dos-doj withoutweekenstatusandholidaysstatus
and includeweekendandholidaystatus

I want output like this:

```
Empid    |   doj         | dos       |includeweekendandholidays  |  witoutincludeweekendandholidayslist
1        |  2015-12-01   |2015-12-06 |    5                      |   3    
2        | 2015-12-01    |2015-12-13 |    12                     |   8
3        | 2015-12-03    |2015-12-13 |    10                     |   6
```

I tried this query:

```
select 
    a.empid, a.doj, a.dos, 
    case 
        when b.weekendstatus = 1 and c.Holidaystatus = 1  
           then datediff(day, c.date, b.date) 
    end as includeweekenandholidays
    case 
        when b.weekendstatus != 1 or c.Holidaystatus = 1  
           then datediff(day, c.date, b.date) 
    end as witoutincludeweekendandholidayslist
from 
    emp a 
left join 
    holidaylist b on a.doj = b.date
left join  
    holidaylist c on a.dos = c.date
```

Above query not given expected result please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in SQL Server

Comment: What does this mean `withoutweekenstatusandholidaysstatus and includeweekendandholidaystatus`?

Comment: Trying joining your tables once, using [date] BETWEEN [doj] AND [dos].  This will give you one row for each day between the start and end dates.  You can filter out records you do not want in the WHERE clause. Now you will have just the records you want, which you can COUNT.

Comment: we need days difference b/w dos and doj for each empid and output need includeweekenandholidayststatusdays means how many days worked  withweekenstatusandholidays  ,withoutweekenstatusandholidaysstatus means need to find how many days he worked without holidaysandweekend daysand weekenddays to find holidayslistandweekendlist look into holidayslist table.please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Comment: The function in T-SQL is called `DATEDIFF` (fixed your post accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
select a.empid,
       a.doj,a.dos, 
       IncludeRest = (select count(h.date) from holidaylist h where e.doj<=h.date AND e.dos>=h.date),
       ExcludeRest = (select count(h.date) from holidaylist h where e.doj<=h.date AND e.dos>=h.date AND h.weekendstatus = 0 AND h.holdaystatus = 0)
from emp e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT a.empid, a.doj, a.dos, 
       DATEDIFF(d, a.doj, a.dos) + 1 AS include,
       DATEDIFF(d, a.doj, a.dos) + 1 - b.wd - b.hd + b.common AS without
FROM emp AS a
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT SUM(weekendStatus) AS wd, 
         SUM(Holidaystatus) AS hd,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN weekendStatus = 1 AND Holidaystatus = 1 THEN 1 END) AS common
  FROM holidaylist
  WHERE [Date] BETWEEN a.doj AND a.dos) AS b
```

For each row of table `emp`, `OUTER APPLY` calculates `weekendStatus=1` and `Holidaystatus=1` rows that correspond to the interval of this row.

Calculated fields selected:

- **include** is the total number of days of the `emp` interval **including** weekend days and holidays.
- **without** is the total number of days of the `emp` interval **minus** weekend days and holidays. *common* field makes sure common weekend days and holidays *are not subtracted twice*.

**Note:** The above query includes start and end days of the interval in the calculations, so the interval considered is [doj - dos]. You can change the predicate of the `WHERE` clause in the `OUTER APPLY` operation so as to exclude start, end, or both, days of the interval.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/546d0/4)

Comment: Hi can you please provide without using outer apply query.when I used same logic in update statement that time outerapply taking more time and its killing performance also.for logic wise give query working fine.I need alternate query please provide it

Comment: @ravi I would recommend trying Jamie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a CASE in your COUNT to determine whether or not to count that day..

```
SELECT
    e.empid,
    e.doj,
    e.dos,
    COUNT(*) includeweekendandholidays,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Holidaystatus = 0
                    AND [weekendStatus] = 0 THEN 1
          END) withoutincludeweekendandholidayslist
FROM
    emp e
    JOIN holidaylist hl ON hl.Date >= e.doj
                           AND hl.Date < e.dos
GROUP BY
    e.empid,
    e.doj,
    e.dos
```

This might perform better since it only joins to holidaylist table on records you need..

```
SELECT
    e.empid,
    e.doj,
    e.dos,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, e.doj, e.dos) includeweekendandholidays,
    COUNT(*) withoutincludeweekendandholidayslist
FROM
    emp e
    JOIN holidaylist hl ON hl.Date BETWEEN e.doj AND e.dos
WHERE 
    weekendStatus = 0 
    AND Holidaystatus = 0
GROUP BY
    e.empid,
    e.doj,
    e.dos,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, e.doj, e.dos)
```

I don't get your output though since it only appears that you're excluding weekends and not holidays..

Answer (score 0):

try another way with cross join

```
select t.empid,t.doj,t.dos,datediff(day,t.doj,t.dos) includeweekendandholidays,
datediff(day,t.doj,t.dos)-isnull(t1.wes,0) as witoutincludeweekendandholidayslist 
from @emp t  left join (

select empid, sum(hd.Holidaystatus+hd.weekendStatus) wes from 
@emp emp cross join @holidaylist hd where hd.[Date]  between doj 
and dateadd(day,-1,dos) group by empid) t1 on t.empid=t1.empid
```

sample data

```
 declare @holidaylist table ([Date] date,  weekendStatus int, Holidaystatus int)
insert into @holidaylist([Date],  weekendStatus, Holidaystatus) values
('2015-12-01' ,   0              , 0),
('2015-12-02' ,   0              , 0),
('2015-12-03' ,   0              , 0),
('2015-12-04' ,   1              , 0),
('2015-12-05' ,   1              , 0),
('2015-12-06' ,   0              , 1),
('2015-12-07' ,   0              , 0),
('2015-12-08' ,   0              , 0),
('2015-12-09' ,   0              , 1),
('2015-12-10' ,   0              , 0),
('2015-12-11' ,   0              , 0),
('2015-12-12' ,   1              , 1),
('2015-12-13' ,   1              , 0)

declare @emp table(empid  int,  doj  date,     dos date)
insert into @emp (empid,doj,dos) values
(1      , '2015-12-01' , '2015-12-06'),
(2      ,'2015-12-01'  , '2015-12-13'),
(3      ,'2015-12-03'  ,'2015-12-13')
```